# Format Excel data in a particular case

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, ms-office, ms-office-script

My data in Excel is

[image]

I want this data using the formula

[image]

Comment: It is more easy using Power Query --> You need to `UNPIVOT` rest of the columns -> select first column and right click unpivot other columns.

Comment: Or do this with formula --> `=LET(_rlabels,A2:A5,
_years,B1:G1,
_yeardata,B2:G5,
HSTACK(TOCOL(IFNA(_rlabels,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(_yeardata)))),TOCOL(IFNA(_years,SEQUENCE(ROWS(_yeardata)))),TOCOL(_yeardata)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `MS365` Formulas and `Power Query`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `I1`

```
=LET(_rlabels,A2:A5,_years,B1:G1,_yeardata,B2:G5,
VSTACK({"Row Labels","Years","Value"},
HSTACK(TOCOL(IFNA(_rlabels,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(_yeardata)))),
TOCOL(IFNA(_years,SEQUENCE(ROWS(_yeardata)))),
TOCOL(_yeardata))))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `M1`

```
=LAMBDA(array,
VSTACK({"Row Labels","Years","Value"},
HSTACK(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",1,
DROP(TAKE(array,,1)&"-"&TAKE(array,1),1,1)),"-","|"),
TOCOL(DROP(array,1,1)))))(A1:G5)
```

---

Or, Using `Power Query`

• Select some cell in your **Data Table**,

• **Data Tab** => **Get&Transform** => **From Table/Range**,

• When the **PQ Editor** opens: **Home** => **Advanced Editor**,

• Make note of all the **2 Tables Names**,

• Paste the `M Code` below in place of what you see.

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DataTbl"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Row Labels"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Attribute", "Years"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Value", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

---

• Change the Table name from **DataTbl** to as **Table_Outputbl** before importing it back into Excel, note that you need to select from **Home** tab --> **Close & Load** --> **Close & Load To** --> Select either **Existing Worksheet** or **New Worksheet** as per your preferences.

---